# Gurobi: Add log term and exponential term be in objective function?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

Is it possible to have exponential terms in objective function in Gurobi? 
I want to optimize the following objective function:

min_x  L2_norm(x-y) + log(b+ exp(k+x))

Gurobi does provide support for log and exponential functions in constraints, but I couldn't find anything for the objective function.
I am using Gurobi's python API.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to formulate this is to add a new auxiliary variable and assign the value of the expression to this variable. This [post in the Gurobi Community](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360056471352-General-constraint-for-arbitrary-function) explains it pretty well.

Comment: I am confused here. I did look into general constraints but isn't  Model.addGenConstrLOG() function act as constraints something like:
min_x L2_norm(x-y) +p 
s.t. p = log(b+ exp(k+x))

Comment: Yes. What's your point? It has to be `min` instead of `min_x` by the way.

Comment: I was worried about the numerical issue, or speed of optimization, as adding a constraint would affect the speed of the optimization (numerically).